# Check if a string from a list is present in a line Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of words `['Ip', 'Name', 'Error']`. Reading a log file, 
the script should test if that line contains one of the words from the list. 
Didn't succeed with 'if list in line' ... any idea ?

Comment: `if any(x in line for x in my_list)`. Do not use the name `list`; you are shadowing the Python built-in

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Iterate over your check list and see it element of list in in line.

**Ex:**

```
 for i in ['Ip', 'Name', 'Error']:
     if i in line:
         print "Ok!!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
list(set(line.split()) & set(my_list))
```

This returns a list of the words present in both the line and the list.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
def getIndexLinesOfWords(filename,word_list):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    dct = {}
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        count += 1
        newLine = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        if newLine == ' ':
            continue
        split_line = newLine.split()
        for word in word_list:
            if word in split_line:
                if word in dct:
                    dct[word] += [count]
                else:
                    dct[word] = [count]
    for word in word_list:
        print('{:12} {}'.format(word,dct[word]))
    infile.close()

filename = "C:/Users/fff/Desktop/log.txt"
word_list = ["lp", "error", "name"]
getIndexLinesOfWords(filename,word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use filter  :

```
data=['Ip', 'Name', 'Error']

print(list(filter(lambda x:[True for line in open('file.txt','r') if x in line],data)))
```